# NuxtJS with CSS Modules through Vue Style Loader causes unexplainable error

Tags: css, webpack, nuxt.js, css-modules

Okay, so I setup a NuxtJS project with the scaffolder and added a few configuration tweaks as to be seen in my [public repo](https://github.com/GitGangGuy/nuxtjs-quickstarter). Everything worked perfectly fine, until I added CSS Modules support, basically copy-pasting the instructions from the official [Vue Style Loader docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html#usage). Somehow, it now complains about the template index file in the pages directory, but in a totally inexplicable manner - the error message doesn't give any hints to what I did wrong, nor does the stack trace show any useful information. I'd appreciate any help, thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-bhabha-joqbx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Have you added a css file to the nuxt.config.js?

Comment: @David Should I have added a css file? According to the examples from the Vue Style Loader docs, it finds components with a `<style module>` tag automatically with the snippets I'm using in the nuxt.config.js file. What css file should I reference anyway, if CSS Modules only work in components themselves?

Comment: Post your code, try posting one in a CodeSandbox.

Comment: @David My Code is up on GitHub, first link in my problem description.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/ It's much better :-)

Comment: @David https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-bhabha-joqbx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark